# To Show that the same correspondence need not yield a ring homomorphism if $n$ does not divide $m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $n$ divides $m$ and that $a$ is an idempotent of $Z_n$ (that is,
$a^2 = a$). To show that the mapping $f(x) = ax$ is a ring homomorphism from $Z_m \to Z_n$. 
To Show that the same correspondence need not yield a ring homomorphism if $n$ does not divide $m$.

Let $x,y \in Z_m$ and $ x=y$, then $x \equiv y \pmod{m}$. Since $n$ divides $m$ therefore by transitivity of divisibility $x \equiv y \pmod{n}$ implies $ax \equiv ay \pmod{n}$ implies $f(x) =f(y)$. Thus $f$ is well defined.

Let $x,y \in Z_m$, then $f(x+y) = a(x+y) = ax +ay = f(x) +f(y)$ and $f(xy) = axy = a^2xy = (ax)(ay) = f(x)f(y)$. Thus one can easily verify that $f$ is a homomorphism.

But I am unable to do the second part. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Pick $a=e$ the multiplicative identity (which is idempotent) and you immediately get a counterexample. Say $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_8$, then $12$ should map to $0$ but it maps to 4 instead...